# Cisco Packet Tracer Dns enable using Router

Tags: cisco

I have a question in Cisco Packet Tracer.
I have a Router and a Dns server and my Config from Dns is blocked. How can I start the DNS server using the Router?

ip dns server ... doesn't work

Thank you

Comment: Add more information / clarification to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Cisco Packet Tracer does not support command "ip dns server" hence you can not use Router like Dns server. 
 
All supported commands you can see in Program_Root_Dir\help\default\index.html or push a question mark in the program.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to attach "WIC 1ENET" in Router to connect it with DNS server

Second, you need an IP address in DNS server For example (192.168.3.2)

Third, enter Gateway like this (192.168.3.1), and DNS server (192.168.3.2)

fourth, Enter the DNS server and go to Services and enter Name and address like this Figure, and then ADD.

Finally, Go to the end Host (PC), then Desktop and then IP Configuration, and Enter the DNS server (192.168.3.2).

I hope that's helpful for you to understand and make it work.

Answer (score -1):

You need enable any routing protocol and add the network where is the DNS Server.